# How to make threading.local() work with non-Python threads?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to find - how to make `threading.local()` work when Python function is called from a non-Python thread.

Let's supposed I have such a function:

```
import threading


var = threading.local()


def fn():
    try:
        print(var.foo)
    except AttributeError:
        print('not ok')
    var.foo = 'ok'
```

If it's called from a non-Python thread that uses C-API to call function `fn()` - `var.foo` would always be unset and `var.foo` value would not be saved between calls even if the thread calling it would be the same.

How to make thread local storage be preserved between calls? Did anybody encounter this problem?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with `threading.local`. For non-`threading` threads, you'll have to use non-`threading` thread-local storage.